# IBM Cognos - How can I place 2 crosstabs under 1 section?

Tags: crosstab, cognos

I'd like to have two `crosstabs` grouped with 1 section similar to this

```
Region A

Crosstab1

Crosstab2

Region B

Crosstab 1

Crosstab 2

Region c.... etc..
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create Crosstab 1
- Section on Region
- Unlock the report
- Create Crosstab 2 underneath Crosstab 1, but within the "Section" container
- Create a Master-Detail relationship in Crosstab 2 to match Crosstab 1 (I find it's useful to turn the icon for these on via Tools->Visual Aids
- Note the Crosstabs will format separately; you may find adding fixed widths on the columns may help presentation